# Prevention of SYN flooding

Tags: security

I am curious how Tor can prevent SYN flooding attacks? From my understanding for a TCP handshake first a SYN has to be sent to the receiver. So why is it not possible to spam various SYN requests over the TOR network, which are then not completed by an ACK after receiving the SYN-ACK from the receiver? What am I missing?

https://support.torproject.org/abuse/what-about-ddos/

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor anonymizes TCP connections by forwarding the stream data. It does not forward packets, and there is no way in Tor to send any specific packets. The exit relay always creates a normal TCP connection to this destination server, and once that connection is established, the exit relay will forward the circuit's stream data to that exit TCP connection.

Comment: Thank you a lot!